# python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm writing a very simple python code to count how many words in the list with a letter in the middle.

```
def middleLetterCounter(wordList, letter):
    letter = letter.lower()
    count = 0
    for words in wordList:
        words = words.lower()
        if (len(words)%2==1 and words[int(len/2)]==letter):
            count += 1
        if (len(words)%2==0 and (words[int(len/2-1)]==letter or words[int(len/2)]==letter)):
            count += 1
    return count
```

To avoid confusion, I choose to convert every word to lowercase first.
I have an error at

```
if (len(words)%2==1 and words[int(len/2)]==letter):
```

And the error is :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'
```

This makes me confused. Obviously the `len(words)%2` is an int, how could it be the building functions? I thought it was the problem of brackets, but it's not.

Comment: There is a lot going on here. Please make a Minimal Reproducible Example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len` is a (built-in) function. You probably meant to call it on `words`:

```py
if (len(words)%2==1 and words[int(len(words)/2)]==letter):
    # Here ---------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `len` when you should use `len(words)`. Also, you can use `//` for integer division instead of `int()`. Also, store it to a variable to avoid repeating yourself:

```py
def middleLetterCounter(wordList, letter):
    letter = letter.lower()
    count = 0
    for words in wordList:
        words = words.lower()
        wordlen = len(words)
        if wordlen % 2 == 1 and words[wordlen // 2] == letter:
            count += 1
        elif wordlen % 2 == 0 and (words[wordlen // 2 - 1] == letter or words[wordlen // 2] == letter):
            count += 1
    return count
```